# Tooltip does not work with Gauge chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, highcharts, extjs6

**Tooltip** does not work with **gauge** chart; using the latest version - **Ext JS 6.0.1 (classic)**.

Here is my tooltip configuration:

```
tooltip: {
    trackMouse: true,
    width: 140,
    height: 28,
    renderer: function(toolTip, record, ctx) {
        toolTip.setHtml(record.get('data1') + '%');
    }
}
```

You can reach the fiddle from [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/vl3).

Comment: Did you init qtip manager Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();?

Comment: yes, I have placed it on the top of `app.js` @yorlin

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [bug](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?294978), that still wasn't fixed. Also from [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Series-cfg-tooltip):

> Note that tooltips are shown for series markers and won't work if the marker is not configured

But it doesn't work even with markers.

Comment: exactly, I have configured the `marker` too as it is guided in API documentation..

Answer (score 0):

Try This
Select Tool Tip from Property Window

[image]

=CStr(Sum(Fields!Fieldname.Value)).